# Time uploading from excel sheet to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, jdbc

I have to insert time values from excel to mysql like in the image below.

[image]

```
int punchin = (int) row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();   
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::: "+punchin);
int punchout = (int) row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::: "+punchout);
int duration = (int) row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println("::::::::::::::::: "+duration);
```

But I couldn't get the proper value.

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL for Excel: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/excel/

It's really easy to use. Once you have installed it, in Excel go to the Data tab and at the end will be Mysql for Excel.

Assuming you've now setup connection to your database, all you now have to do is the following:

1. Select all the data excluding the columns.
2. On the side panel, click the database table that you will be putting the data into.
3. Click Append Excel Data to Table.
4. Map any columns in the data to your database columns using the tool provided at this poiont.
5. Click append and wait.
6. Your data should now be uploaded.